# Use a factor column in "by" and do not drop empty factors

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table:

```
x <- data.table(x=runif(3), group=factor(c('a','b','a'), levels=c('a','b','c')))
```

I want to know how many rows in `x` exist for each `group`:

```
x[, .N, by="group"]
#    group N
# 1:     a 2
# 2:     b 1
```

**Question: is there some way to force the above `by="group"` to consider all levels of the factor `group`?**

Notice how since I don't have any rows of with `group` 'c' in the table, I don't get a row for c.

Desired output:

```
x[, .N, by="group", ???] # somehow use all levels in `group`
#    group N
# 1:     a 2
# 2:     b 1
# 3:     c 0
```

Comment: Why not add the missing levels afterwards, something like `merge(y,data.table(group=levels(x[,group])),by="group",all=TRUE)` and then turn `NA`s into 0?

Comment: I don't know a general solution, but for `.N` alone, you can fall back on `table`: `x[,table(group)]` (as you probably already know).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are willing to run through the factor levels by enumerating them in `i` (rather than by setting `by="group"`), this will get you the hoped for results.

```
setkey(x, "group")
x[levels(group), .N, by=.EACHI]
#    group N
# 1:     a 2
# 2:     b 1
# 3:     c 0
```

Comment: @Henrik -- Good catch! Thanks for that. Changed them both.

Answer (score 0):

With the `on=` argument (introduced to data.table with CRAN version 1.9.6 as of 19 Sep 2015) we can achieve the same result as in [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543706/3817004) *without setting keys*:

```
x[.(group = levels(group)), on = .(group), .N, by = .EACHI]
```

> ```
>    group N
> 1:     a 2
> 2:     b 1
> 3:     c 0
> ```

or shorter but less self-explanatory

```
x[.(levels(group)), on = .(group = V1), .N, by = .EACHI]
```