# Empty factors in "by" data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that has factor column with empty levels. I need to get the row count and sums of other variables, all grouped by multiple factors, including the one with empty levels. 
My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542193/use-a-factor-column-in-by-and-do-not-drop-empty-factors), but here I need to count for multiple factors.

For example, let data.table be:

```
library('data.table')

dtr <- data.table(v1=sample(1:15), 
v2=factor(sample(letters[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),levels=letters[1:5]),
v3=sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to do the following:

```
dtr[,list(freq=.N,mm=sum(v1,na.rm=T)),by=list(v2,v3)]

#Output is:
   v2  v3 freq mm
1:  b yes    4 22
2:  b  no    1 13
3:  c  no    3 10
4:  a  no    4 49
5:  c yes    1 10
6:  a yes    2 16
```

I want output include empty levels for v2 as well ("d" and "e"), like in `table(dtr$v2,dtr$v3)`, so the final output should look like (the order doesn't matter):

```
   v2  v3 freq mm
1:  b yes    4 22
2:  b  no    1 13
3:  c  no    3 10
4:  a  no    4 49
5:  c yes    1 10
6:  a yes    2 16
7:  d yes    0 0
8:  d no    0 0
9:  e yes    0 0
10:  e no    0 0
```

I tried to use the method used in the link, but I'm not sure how to use joint J() function when there are multiple columns used.

This works fine for groupping by 1 column only:

```
setkey(dtr,v2)
dtr[J(levels(v2)),list(freq=.N,mm=sum(v1,na.rm=T))]
```

However, `dtr[J(levels(v2),v3),list(freq=.N,mm=sum(v1,na.rm=T))]` doesn't include all combinations

Comment: I found that if I change the order of values and set `setkey(dtr,v3,v2)` and  `unique(dtr[J(v3,levels(v2)),list(freq=.N,mm=sum(v1,na.rm=T))])` will work, but could anyone please explain why and will it work for the big data.table with more than 2 groups?

Comment: Thanks @Asayat. I've filed in a FR #4914 here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4914&group_id=240&atid=978

Comment: The link to R-Forge is broken. The feature request can now be found on github https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/562.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dtr <- data.table(v1=sample(1:15), 
                  v2=factor(sample(letters[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),levels=letters[1:5]),
                  v3=sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE))

res <- dtr[,list(freq=.N,mm=sum(v1,na.rm=T)),by=list(v2,v3)]
```

You can use `CJ` (a cross join). Doing this after aggregation avoids setting the key for the big table and should be faster.

```
setkey(res,c("v2","v3"))
res[CJ(levels(dtr[,v2]),unique(dtr[,v3])),]

#    v2  v3 freq mm
# 1:  a  no    1  9
# 2:  a yes    2 11
# 3:  b  no    2 11
# 4:  b yes    3 23
# 5:  c  no    4 40
# 6:  c yes    3 26
# 7:  d  no   NA NA
# 8:  d yes   NA NA
# 9:  e  no   NA NA
# 10:  e yes   NA NA
```

Comment: with >5*10^6 rows and > 300 factor levels tapply will run forever :)

Comment: @Arun It would make sense from the statistical point of view to handle empty factor levels like this.

Comment: @Asayat No, Arun is talking about improving data.table to handle factors like `tapply` does.

Comment: Sorry, @Arun, just got it :) shame there is no data.table package to my mind to handle this :)

Answer (score 1):

`table()` will also capture freq values that are zero. To get the "mm" column, you could do a basic join. For example,

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dtr <- data.table(v1=sample(1:15), 
                  v2=factor(sample(letters[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),levels=letters[1:5]),
                  v3=sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE))
res <- as.data.table(dtr[,table(v2,v3)])
setnames(res,'N','freq')
setkey(res,v2,v3)
setkey(dtr,v2,v3)
res <- dtr[,.(mm=sum(v1,na.rm=TRUE)),by=c('v2','v3')][res]
```

I'm not sure how `table()` benchmarks with cross join.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers helped me a lot, but I needed a version that can be run programmatically; i.e. the columns to be combined may vary from case to case.

Here's what I did, in case someone needs it. Note that it requires the variables in the data.table to be factors:

```
library('data.table')
# create the data table
dtr <- data.table(v1=sample(1:15), 
v2=factor(sample(letters[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),levels=letters[1:5]),
v3=factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE)))

# select the columns to be used as key
cols <- c('v2', 'v3')
setkeyv(dtr, cols)

# get all combinations of the levels in selected column
keyobject <- expand.grid(lapply(dtr[, ..cols], levels))

# get summary for each combination
dtr[keyobject, .(freq=.N,mm=sum(v1,na.rm=T)), by = .EACHI]
```

Edit: You may also use `do.call(CJ, lapply(dtr[, ..cols], levels))` instead of `expand.grid`